# Update selectInput() choices after editing rhandsontable in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app in which I use a `numericInput()` "tests" to add rows to the dataframe. Then I give the names of the "Label" column as choices to the `selectInput()` "Label2". The problem is that when I edit the names in column "Label" of the table the `selectInput()` choices are not updated accordingly. For example if I rename "Test 1" to "Test A" in the table I want it to change in the selectInput() as well.

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               rHandsontableOutput("hot3"),
               uiOutput("book12")

             )
           )))
#server.r
server <- function(input, output,session) {



  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2", "#tests", value = 1, min=1)
  })

  output$book12<-renderUI({

    selectInput("bk12", 
                "Label2", 
                choices=(rt4()$Label))
  })
  rt4<-reactive({
    DF <- data.frame(
      Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  })

  output$hot3 <-renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(rt4())

  )
}
```

Comment: Look up updateselectinput for this

Comment: I take "operator is invalid for atomic vectors" when I use updateSelectInput()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. You were not reading back the edited `rhandsontable`
in your code.
So i ve added an `observe` to do this

```
 observe({
    if(!is.null(input$hot3))
      rt4$DF <- hot_to_r(input$hot3)
  })
```

Also in the code, Ive added some `req` statements to check for NULL conditions at the time of initialisation, you can use the if..else mechanism that you have used in some of your other questions too.

```
 #ui.r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               rHandsontableOutput("hot3"),
               uiOutput("book12")

             )
           )))
#server.r
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  rt4<- reactiveValues()

  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2", "#tests", value = 1, min=1)
  })

  output$book12<-renderUI({

    selectInput("bk12",
                "Label2",
                choices=(rt4$DF$Label))
  })


  observe({

    req(input$text2)

    rt4$DF <- data.frame(
      Test=paste(1:input$text2),
      Label=paste("Test",1:isolate(input$text2)),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  })
  output$hot3 <-renderRHandsontable({
    req(input$text2)
    rhandsontable(rt4$DF)
    } )

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$hot3))
      rt4$DF <- hot_to_r(input$hot3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: That is an exceptional answer. Thanks for the useful fixes!

Comment: Question: What does 'req(input$text2)' do in renderRHandsontable?

Comment: It handles Null values and blanks. Essentially, the rest of the code beneath req executes only if the conditions within Req are nonblanks. It doesn’t have anything to do with rhandsontable as such